# Javascript Validation in Django Admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'd like to use Javascript to validate forms in the Django admin interface. I was going to use [this jQuery plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), but I wanted to make sure that there wasn't some other Django conventional way to do it. I looked around a bit and didn't see anything, but I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: I would also really like to know this, seems like a strange omission.

Comment: Googled [django-validforms](https://github.com/ulf/django-validforms), have you checked it out?

Comment: the plugin you posted is the way to go, its written by one of the JQuery contributors and is the de facto standard on the web. Not sure what Django uses if anything sorry - if there is some validation there though it wouldn't be hard to inspect source and/or use firebug to find out right!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of javascripts Django admin loads by default on `change_form.html` template:

```
core.js
admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js
js/jquery.min.js
js/jquery.init.js
js/actions.min.js
```

None of these seems to contain client side validation code. So, you can use it safely.